# A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities ["which" or "and"?] has many financial responsibilities

Tags: subjects, ellipses, which-that

I've asked in textranch.com to correct a sentence I've written which I was not sure of:

> 1) A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities which has many financial responsibilities.

I was corrected to:

> 2) A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities and has many financial responsibilities.

Why is the first sentence wrong and the second right? Is it possible in the second sentence that the subject is not expressed? Why? Thank you in advance

Comment: Certainly. The sentence has one subject (*a bursar) with a compound verb (*is...and..has*).  You could also say *An important figure in UK and US universities is the bursar, who has many financial responsibilities.*

Comment: It might be noted that there are differences between British English and American English regarding the acceptable use of "which". I expect in British English no correction would be thought needed, while in US English, "which" is usually used for non-human references, and humans are referenced by "who". Since a bursary is human, a speaker of US English would usually use "who".

Comment: @brasshat 'Which' is totally unacceptable in this usage here in the UK too. Please give support for your claim; I suspect you're confusing this with the use of 'that' after 'The man' etc. But John Lawler [US] has said that 'the man that I know' is as acceptable as 'the man who I know'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth, in the Book of Common Prayer of the Church of England, the text reads "Our Father, which art in heaven,..."; in the US editions of the Book of Common Prayer, the very same text has always been rendered "Our Father, who art in heaven,...". The same difference is typically found between the 1602 AV of the scriptures, where the relevant passage in Matthew in copies printed in the UK read "which" while copies printed in the US by US publishers that I have examined of the exact verse read "who".

Comment: I get so tired of these supposed differences between AE and BE when they are so OFF.

Comment: Do you think we actually speak in AV? It's an archaic usage, preserved by a small minority in just about one set text. Less than 2% of the population regularly even attend Anglican services. We've stopped speaking in Shakespearean too. 'A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities which has many financial responsibilities.' would be marked wrong in 100% of UK schools.

Comment: @brasshat. This is not about British vs American. It is about the difference between 17th century English and 21st century English.

Answer (score 4):

There are several options here, which can be seen as grammatically correct:

- A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities **who** has many financial responsibilities.
- A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities, **having** many financial responsibilities.
- A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities, **with** many financial responsibilities.
- A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities, **holding** many financial responsibilities.

You could also reword it, so:

- Bursars in UK and US universities are typically important figures, holding many financial responsibilities.
- The bursar, in UK and US universities, is an important figure due to his or her significant financial responsibilities.

Using which to describe a person isn't good grammar, since who is more typical.

Comment: A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities who has many financial responsibilities. No, that is wrong. Universities who??  The most obvious form you don't even mention: |A bursar in the UK and US is an important figure with many financial responsibilities.|

Comment: really? I'd think that was pretty obvious what I meant.

Comment: Your first four examples are very awkward English. Sorry, just a fact. They sound unedited.

Comment: I'd upvote you except for the awkward gerunds in your 2nd and 4th suggestions.

Comment: they are not awkward at all, but grammatically correct in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

//A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities which has many financial responsibilities.
I was corrected to:
2) A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities and has many financial responsibilities. //

As a professional editor, I would phrase it thus:

**A bursar in UK and US universities is an important figure with many financial responsibilities.**

Simpler is always better. No gerunds, no commas and no compound sentence.

Comment: ***And*** a slight change in meaning. If the OP was defining *bursar,* and trying to get across the point that the position of bursar only exists in education institutions, you've completely lost this nuance.

Comment: It is a rewrite of A bursar in UK and US universities is an important figure with many financial responsibilities. And mine is better. :) The idea "that they only exist in US and UK universities" is not there.  What is there is the definition of one function in two separate places where the term has the same meaning.

Comment: But the OP's sentence was "A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities which has many financial responsibilities." You're rewriting the wrong sentence. Compare *The tsar was the ruler of the Russian people who had absolute power* and *The tsar of the Russian people was a ruler with absolute power.* You can't just shuffle clauses around like that and expect it to mean exactly the same thing.

Comment: A bursar is an important figure in UK and US universities, idea one. Idea two: bursars have many financial responsibilities.  My sentence reflects that. The OP is not saying the position of bursar **only exists in educational institutions**.  It is not even suggested....